# How do I turn off HTTP caching for an Azure App Service Web App if my app is just a simple HTML page?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I presently have an application that's just an HTML page (with a bunch of JavaScript making calls to a bunch of API's to make it look interactive).

But at the end of the day, presently, my entire app is just a single HTML page.

I deployed it on **Azure App Service** as a **Web App**.

I want to turn off HTTP caching everywhere -- server, intermediaries / proxies, and the client. How do I do that without resorting to the not-recommended HTML `<meta>` tags?

I am looking at the **Application Settings** for the **App Service** but I don't see any option to turn off caching. I am presently on the **F1 tier** **App Service Plan** that's free, so I am guessing that's why they won't let me access the web server settings because it's (actually even lower than) shared across other apps of other customers?

But can you confirm that a **Basic** or upwards plan will let you control server options for an **App Service** (and not for a VM you have provisioned)?

Answer (score 4):

You can disable Local Cache on a per-web-app basis by using this **app setting**: WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION = Never.

By upgrading to Not-Free plans you will get lots of benefits but local caching is not one of them. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/

Comment: Thank you. I have since upgraded to a more commercial oriented plan that allows SSL bindings as well and set up a server side application to return the required headers to prevent caching. I will try out what you said in a test application in a day or so and mark this answer correct.